# Add a map element with a frame border and background

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to insert a north arrow and a legend into the map with a white background frame and a border with a 3pt gap. The code below partially works, but it changes the background colour of the dataframe as well (which I don't want) and does not change the north arrow size to 125. The code below is just for the north arrow.

[image: Picture of Legend property dialog with Frame tab selected]

```
Private Sub NorthArrowAdder2(ByVal pArrow As INorthArrow, ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double)
    Dim activeView As IActiveView
    Dim gc As IGraphicsContainer
    gc = m_pMxDoc.ActiveView
    gc.Reset()
    Dim mapSurround As IMapSurround
    mapSurround = pArrow  ' QI
    pArrow.Size = 125

    Dim mapSurroundFrame As IMapSurroundFrame
    Dim mapFrame As IMapFrame = gc.FindFrame(m_pMxDoc.Maps.Item(0))
    Dim pUid As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID
    pUid.Value = "esricore.MarkerNorthArrow"
    mapSurroundFrame = mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame(pUid, pArrow)

    '***** set anchor point 
    Dim element2 As IElementProperties3 = mapSurroundFrame
    element2.AnchorPoint = esriAnchorPointEnum.esriTopLeftCorner

    '***** white background
    Dim backGround As IBackground
    backGround = mapFrame.Background ' match background to map frame
    backGround.Gap = 3
    Dim symBackground As ISymbolBackground = backGround
    Dim fillSymbol As IFillSymbol = symBackground.FillSymbol
    Dim colour As IRgbColor = New RgbColor
    colour.Red = 255
    colour.Blue = 255
    colour.Green = 255
    fillSymbol.Color = colour
    symBackground.FillSymbol = fillSymbol
    symBackground.Gap = 2
    mapFrame.Background = backGround

    activeView = m_pMxDoc.ActiveView
    Dim pElem As IElement = mapSurroundFrame
    pElem.Geometry = NorthGeometry(x, y)
    gc.AddElement(pElem, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting mapFrame.Background = backGround, if the symbol for backGround has changed at all you're overwriting it, try commenting out that line. Try setting your pArrow.Size *before* you cast it to mapSurround.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Setting pArrow.Size = 125 before mapSurround = pArrow worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @MichaelMiles-Stimson comment,  the arrow size has to be set before it is cast to mapSurround.

```
pArrow.Size = 125
Dim mapSurround As IMapSurround
mapSurround = pArrow  ' QI
```

The other problem was in the 7th last line in my code above.
I was setting **mapFrame**.Background = backGround,
it should be **mapSurroundFrame**.Background = backGround

```
....
symBackground.Gap = 3
mapSurroundFrame.Background = backGround
....
```